# Alarm received correctly when due, but incorrectly a second time when app is opened afterwards

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am able to get notifications at a particular time in future by using Calendar class java (Example 9:15am). The Alarm manager sends the broadcast to the broadcast receiver whenever the time is 9:15am but when I open the app after 9:15am (Example 9:20am). I receive the same notification. Can anyone help my about this.

My Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".others.NotificationReceiver"/>
```

Notification Receiver.java

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        createNotification(context);
    }

    private void createNotification(Context context) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel linkChannel = new NotificationChannel(link_channel_id, "Link Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            linkChannel.setDescription("This channel is used to show Zoom Links");
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(linkChannel);
        }

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, link_channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle("Test Notification")
                .setContentText("This is a test notification")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
}
```

My Alarm Manager

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        myIntent1.setAction(ACTION_ONE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, myIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
```

Comment: Make sure NotificationReceiver is not triggered programmatically on launch.

Comment: @AjayGurappanavar How can I do that?